# Issue With JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a weird issue with some JSON data.

```
{
    "title" : "Counties",
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "Baker",
            "latlng": [
                "44.65488,-118.42475",
                "44.64548,-118.38275",
                "44.62488,-118.34425",
                "0,0",
                "1,0"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I use .getJSON for the file with this data I am getting an syntax error but if I take out the last two entries from the latlng array it will work correctly.

I put the JSON though the linter at jsonlint.com and it says it's valid JSON but chrome and firefox can't parse it for some reason.

The code that is getting the json file:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("json/counties.json", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });

    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){
        console.log(exception);
    });
});
```

The exception that is logged from Chrome

```
SyntaxError {}
```

And the exception that is logged from Firefox

```
[15:07:33.965] (new SyntaxError("JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", 3))
```

As far as I can tell there aren't any characters after the JSON in the data, here's a screen shot

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: It is valid JSON, so we'll need more information, like the code that you're using to try to parse it, and the error you're seeing.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/w3vuQ/. Maybe your cannot handle the last two entries properly. But then you need to post your code, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: I tried this in Chrome, are you doing something else?

temp.data[0].latlng[1]
"44.64548,-118.38275"
temp.data[0].latlng[2]
"44.62488,-118.34425"
temp.data[0].latlng[2]
"44.62488,-118.34425"
temp.data[0].latlng[3]
"0,0"
temp.data[0].latlng[4]
"1,0"

So in chrome it works, please paste more code you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is all working fine for me, and the data you're showing is fine, so there must just be something weird going on in your environment.

First thing I'd suggest is to watch your raw HTTP response in Fiddler or your browser's network tab, and see if there's anything unexpected there - maybe you've got a proxy server appending garbage to your data or something like that.

If not, then try opening up your `counties.json` file in a binary editor and look for any unexpected byte in there, maybe something invisible or a funky quotation mark or something. This is all ASCII here in your example, so it should be pretty easy to spot any character that doesn't belong.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the problem is. Vagrant is doing something weird again and appending stuff to the end of some files.